# Does it matter if my website has build errors?

Tags: asp.net, kentico

I am a C# winforms programmer, not used to ASP.Net.
As a winforms programmer I build regularly to detect syntax errors.

Recently I opened a Kentico website in Visual Studio and to my surprise found that there were build errors.

Does this matter?

My instinct is to go about correcting the site until it builds.  This is a side track from what I set out to do.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Kentico but ASP.NET should definitely build without errors. Certain warnings may be acceptable but even that should be rare.

Comment: Can you list the reasons ?

Comment: Again, I'm speaking just about ASP.NET not Kentico.. If your project encounters even one error, then the .dll for that project is not built. If you launch then it is using the last version that successfully compiled. ASP.NET does so much magic in the background that it's very possible for stuff to look ok on the surface. For example: the updated html in your code-in-fronts looks new but the code-behind is old because of the error. I'd treat it no different as compiling an .exe. If it build fails, you can't run it.

Comment: but the weird thing is that it does run.  The changes the developers make to the ascx and ascx.cs files do appear on the website.  This might be to do with web parts.

Comment: I was purposely trying to avoid the messy details of ASP.NET dynamic compilation, but it's possible to have errors and have some changes work. Many things affect how many .DLLs are automagically compiled. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s10awwz0(v=vs.85).aspx Errors may only affect one batch while others are ok. It's also possible for the code-in-front (.ascx) to be separate from the code-behind (.ascx.cs). If you were to use the command line pre-compile tool, however, it would fail fatal and stop compiling on the first error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are attempting to build any kind of quality into your project/software, then yes, it does matter if it builds.

Regarding Kentico and build times, if you're using a website vs. a web project, yes the build times are typically longer and range anywhere from a few minutes to I've seen upwards of an hour.  The build times depend greatly on the machine building it as well.  So if your machine has a Celeron processor, with 1GB of RAM and a 5400 RPM drive, you're going to take longer to build than a machine with an i7 processor, 16GB of RAM and a solid state hard drive that can read/write 500+ MB/s.  Also keep in mind Kentico out of the box has over 9000 system files in it so as a website, it will take some time to build.

One of the first things I check when a site doesn't build is to ensure all the referenced DLLs are in the website/project.  If not, this will cause several errors and is usually a very simple fix. If you have any kind of errors from code which resides in the /App_Code directory, your site will NOT run at all when you publish it.  If you have errors within any other directory, the site will run BUT wherever those code files are referenced on the website, will display errors.  So in your instance if you have webpart files in the /CMSWebparts/OurCompany folder, if those webparts are placed on pages within the website, those pages will error out even though the rest of the site is running.

In my opinion, just fix the errors and be done with them.  Then check the code into a version control system to keep track of the changes.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this matter?

It depends on what you are trying to achieve with your website. If you want to make it available to the public then building is definitely something you should consider as top priority. If on the other hand you want to have the source code open in Visual Studio on your local machine, just for reading purposes, then building is not necessary.

Comment: Thanks Darin... but why?  to catch errors? for speed for the user experience?  The build is taking hours so I can understand why the other developers have not been doing it.  It is a commercial website, so browsing speed definitely matters.

Comment: Well, if you don't compile your code, it will not work at runtime. It's the whole point of compilation.

Comment: If this is a new endeavor, I'd seriously reconsider using any CMS framework that takes hours to build! Or perhaps, your code is some kind of extension or plugin? In that case, then maybe *yes* skip compiling the framework itself. But in that case you need to run the official binary distribution and not a half-compiled/broken version of your own.

Comment: Our code is in ascx and ascx.cs files inside CMSWebParts\OurCompany folder
There is no dll but the changes appear on the website. How can this be if we aren't compiling it?

Comment: By default, IIS/ASP.NET is automagically compiling on the fly and the .DLLs live deep in a temp folder under C:\Windows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx. To get the true picture, you can use precompilation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398860.aspx

Comment: Thank you. In one build I only had 1 error, but then when i fix that error and re-build a whole lot of new unrelated errors appear.  In a winforms project I would get all the errors at once.  Is there any way I can get such a picture using ASP.Net ?